# Excluding server-side only modules from webpack compilation for client app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, webpack

I develop web applications based on NodeJS and React. I have been playing around different architecture style and recently obsessed with this idea to share code across server-side and client-side. I think this style is powerful because it can reduce the difficulty of maintaining continuity of API.

Here's a simple example of how client-side imports types from server-side:

- https://github.com/hoiekim/budget/blob/main/src/client/lib/call.ts

I want to develop this style even more so I can write requesting and responding part of APIs in one place and both server-side and client-side import it from the same source. Webpack will compile and tree-shake them separately so I don't have to worry about the bundle size growing too big.

The problem is, when server-side module has dependencies to modules that are not supported in browsers, but not directly used in client-side, like "bcrypt", webpack will throw errors while compiling React app. I tried using "externals" option in webpack configuration.

```
{
  ...
  externals: ["bcrypt", ...]
  ...
}
```

But I get errors in runtime because webpack adds lines like this without defining the variable "bcrypt"

```
modules.exports = bcrypt
```

Note that using browser supporting version of bcrypt doesn't solve the problem since my pain point is not specific for bcrypt. I want a solution applicable for any kind of modules available in NPM.

I know it's not a recommended way of engineering and because of that not a lot of resources are developed the way supports this idea but I think it will totally work for my personal projects, and who knows it will be a thing some day? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution myself, finally.

Webpack uses `browser` property in `package.json` to determine entry point for the package so we can create a tiny sub-package that imports a desired module differently for the server and the client.

Here's an example that I actually commented about for a similar issue that is currently open for [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11756#issuecomment-1872220127).

> For example for `crypto`,
>
> 1. Create a folder called `crypto`
> 2. Create `package.json` under `crypto` folder and configure like this:
>
>    ```
>    {
>      "browser": "client.js",
>      "main": "server.js",
>      "types": "index.d.ts" // optional
>    }
>    ```
> 3. Create a file `crypto/client.js`
>
>    ```
>    // crypto/client.js
>    module.exports = window.crypto
>    ```
> 4. Create a file `crypto/server.js`
>
>    ```
>    // crypto/server.js
>    module.exports = require("crypto").webcrypto
>    ```
>
> Now import `crypto` folder you just created. Hope it makes sense.

You can even do some dummy exports if you think it's safe and that way pretty much any modules can be compiled for browsers.